# ASP MVC - El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo ... pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un problema con ASP MVC. Tengo el siguiente controller:

```
    public ActionResult Datos()
    {
        personaModel persona;
        persona = (personaModel)Session["personaLogedIn" + Session.SessionID];
        return View(persona);
    }
```

Y la siguiente vista:

```
@model ProgIII_EasyFitness_RoccaFederico.Models.personaModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Datos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAlumno.cshtml";
}

<h2>Datos</h2>
...
```

El problema es que cuando acceso a esta vista, entrando por el controller, la aplicación me arroja la siguiente excepción:

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo
>   'ProgIII_EasyFitness_RoccaFederico.Models.personaModel', pero este
>   diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo
>   'ProgIII_EasyFitness_RoccaFederico.Service.personaService'.

Lo que no estoy entiendiendo es el motivo, ya que el tipo de dato que retorno en el controlador, es el mismo tipo de dato del modelo de la vista.

personaModel es mi clase de datos:

```
namespace ProgIII_EasyFitness_RoccaFederico.Models
{
    public class personaModel
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
        public int dni { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public usuarioModel user { get; set; }
        public personaModel()
        {
            if(user == null)
            {
                user = new usuarioModel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mientras que personaService es una clase únicamente con métodos:

```
namespace ProgIII_EasyFitness_RoccaFederico.Service
{
    public class personaService
    {
        public personaModel getPersonaByMailAndDNI(string Mail, int DNI)...
        public personaModel getPersonaByMailAndPassword(string Mail, string password)...
        public bool checkPersonExistence(personaModel persona)...
        public void newPersona(personaModel persona)...
        public long getLastPersonaID()...
    }
}
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Puedes indicar en la pregunta las clases `personaModel` y `personaService`?. Hay algún tipo de herencia entre la dos?

Comment: Esto parece estar todo bien. La Vista se llama `Datos.cshtml`?

Comment: `Session["personaLogedIn" + Session.SessionID]` donde y cómo lo asignas?.

Comment: Viene asignado desde antes (Desde el login). Si tu pregunta es si llega null no, ya lo verifiqué con el debug, y persona está cargado correctamente con todos los datos.
Es correcto, la vista se llama Datos.cshtml

Comment: Tienes algún modelo `@model` definido en `_LayoutAlumno.cshtml`?

Comment: Estás en lo correcto. Desconozco por qué, pero tenia referenciado el model de personaService en el layout, cosa que es incorrecta. Gracias por apuntarme al problema. Podes comentar una respuesta así la marco como aceptada, o preferís que lo haga yo directamente?

Comment: Ok, añado la respuesta, así queda constancia de la solución al problema para otros usuarios.

Comment: Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, y marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Comment: Rafael, lo tengo en cuenta. Pero al valorar tu respuesta como aceptada, ya que lo es, me indica: "¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente tengas dos directivas **`@model`** que estén interfiriendo la una con la otra.

Suele pasar cuando definimos un **`@model`** en la Vista y otro en la página maestra.

Revisa tu página maestra `_LayoutAlumno.cshtml` a ver si tienes un `@model ProgIII_EasyFitness_RoccaFederico.Service.personaService` y elimínalo.